# Have I locked myself out of Anri of Astora's Slayer of Aldrich ending?

Tags: dark-souls-3

This is my first run of Dark Souls 3, so I skipped a lot of side quests unknowingly and am trying to get back to doing them.

Here's the rundown of what I have done:

1. I've met Anri of Astora and Horace the Hushed at the Halfway Fortress and summoned them for Deacons of the Deep.
2. I've talked to them again at Firelink Shrine after defeating the Deacons of the Deep.
3. I've met Anri at the Catacombs and didn't tell her Horace's Location.
4. I made Yuria of Londor come to Firelink Shrine, then killed her after I cured my hollowing.
5. I've killed Pontiff Sulyvahn without summoning Anri.

However, I have *not* killed the pilgrim in the Church of Yorshka bonfire area, but I am planning to.

I want her to be alive to summon for Aldrich's boss battle. Have I locked myself out of the Slayer of Aldrich ending?

Comment: Did Anri show up at the Church of Yorshka bonfire for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (without spoilers), yes, you forgot to do something and now she is gone.

This is a huge spoiler, so if you want to find everything yourself, don't read this:

> Anri will die if you dont save her from the pilgrim at the Church of Yorshka bonfire. This will cause you to "fail" the questline for Anri.

BTW: wiki -> [Anri](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Anri+of+Astora)

Comment: Apologies for the edit comment. I'm doing this on a Mac and it likes to quickly autofill in other edit comments I've made right before I hit the "submit" button...

Comment: Technically I would disagree on your wording, because she is involved in two questlines. However, the alternate questline does require a lot more to be done, so unless that has been completed,  then yes.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Anri of Astora wikia page](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Anri+of+Astora), it looks like she/he (depending on what you chose for your own character's gender) will not appear until you have killed [Horace the Hushed](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Horace+the+Hushed) in the Smouldering Lake.

> NOTE: Anri's summon sign for Aldrich will not appear **unless Horace is killed in Smouldering Lake**

However, based on [IGN's page on the Anri of Astora questlines](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dark-souls-3/Anri_of_Astora), it looks like you've been locked out of the Anri of Astora alternate questline regardless:

> Step 9 - IMPORTANT: Immediately after speaking to Anri in the church, head towards the door you just came through. To your right are several statues of children with swords. A Pilgrim of Londor will be hiding as one of the statues. Kill her to continue this questline. **Not killing her will lead to Anri dying prematurely.**

Because you killed Pontiff Sulyvahn before killing the pilgrim, I believe you have locked yourself out of the Anri questline to kill Aldrich together. I do not think that leaving Horace alive as long as you have would have locked you out, though it will need to be done, but Anri's death definitely did.